# What would Brexit mean for my immediate Europe travel plans from the UK?

Tags: uk, europe, eu, eu-citizens, brexit

I am planning a trip from England to Croatia in this coming July 2016, one month after the [EU referendum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Kingdom_European_Union_membership_referendum) will have taken place in the United Kingdom.

**How would the possibility of Britain leaving the European Union in June affect these travel plans?** Would I have to get visas at short notice or would EU freedom of travel still be a possible?

I have searched low and high on the internet looking for detailed information regarding this topic. I'm looking for an official source (Government/EU source or *trusted* news article) which confirms definitively whether or not I will require a visa. I will upvote useful input but will not accept answers which are simply opinions stated without sources.

Comment: Hi, Swiss person here: Switzerland was never a member of the EU, so there was no exit. However Switzerland is part of the Schengen agreement (as opposed to UK). Anyway, even though Switzerland is not part of the EU, Swiss people don't need a visa to travel to EU countries, including those outside of the Schengen area (such us UK, Croatia or Ireland). I think as of now this is only speculative, but I highly doubt that a visa will be needed to travel to Croatia or any other EU country as a UK citizen.

Comment: One would think that even if the majority voted for leaving, there would be a fair period of time between the vote and when the exit was legally finalized.  No government bureaucracy works that quick ;-)  Plus one would think that as a UK citizen, you would still have fairly relaxed entry rules like Americans do in EU (unless the EU gets petty about the exit).

Comment: @drat I was not aware, pardon my ignorance! I have updated the question to reflect this fact since the Swiss situation no longer pertains to my scenario. Helpful input though, thank you!

Comment: If there's a Brexit, you will not see anything tangible or different until 2020. And that's if all the members act according to deadlines.

Comment: At the moment this question is a broadly speculative opinion survey. Close voting accordingly.

Comment: @GayotFow I'm looking for an official source (Government/EU source or trusted news article) which either confirms definitively whether or not I will require a visa. I will upvote useful input but will not accept answers which are simply opinions stated without sources, in line with the community principles of this site. If you provide a source to your comment and post it as an answer I will accept it unless a more helpful one comes along.

Comment: @drat, Switzerland has existing treaties on free travel. The UK would have to negotiate new ones.

Comment: You wouldn't find anything like a 'trusted news article' making a statement about visas at the moment because it's silly. Pure speculation.  Sure, there are working groups out there but their minutes are not publically distributed. Whether UK citizens will need visas or not will be a result of the exit negotiations. Negotiations will not begin until after all the members have responded to the consultation. They will be thorny and drawn out and the first changes will be customs and duty.  2020 at the earliest.  Take it or leave it :)

Comment: Tourists are 99% likely to remain unaffected (all developed countries in the world can visit the EU visa free at this moment). It's those who live abroad for a long time that will suffer, especially the people who didn't bother applying for permanent residence despite living abroad for many years.

Comment: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/live/uk-politics-35601369

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There will be absolutely no change for you. No change in visa requirements. No change in anything.

Firstly, post-referendum the UK government need to work out terms of the exit. Based on prior examples, this could take forever! Then, [Article 50 gives a timeline at 2 years from notifying the EU of exit terms](http://www.lisbon-treaty.org/wcm/the-lisbon-treaty/treaty-on-European-union-and-comments/title-6-final-provisions/137-article-50.html).

> 3. The Treaties shall cease to apply to the State in question from the date of entry into force of the withdrawal agreement or, failing that, two years after the notification referred to in paragraph 2, unless the European Council, in agreement with the Member State concerned, unanimously decides to extend this period.

O.m. Is slightly misguided - there is no way to immediately do this.

Comment: +1, v nice. Also, the Referendum Act 2015 provides that a 'yes' vote merely authorizes the government to *INFORM* the EU of its intentions. That's all. After that, Lisbon kicks in :)

Comment: No - very different case :-)

Comment: Nah - it's a minimum **after** the UK gov come to an agreement. It's not a maximum - even the wording is specific on this. Realistically, after referendum, we will have a year or two while UK gov decide how to do it, then at least 2 years from the agreement.

Comment: Funnily enough three and a half years later Brexit is still not finalized, so "forever" is indeed the right word

Answer (score 4):

Almost certainly there is no immediate effect. Whatever the outcome of the vote, there will be a lengthy transitional period.

However, one cannot categorically exclude the possibility that the UK government declares an immediate exit the day after the vote and that the rest of the EU reacts by accepting immediately.

Comment: Accepting immediately...  Doesn't Article 50 of the Lisbon Treaty call for two years?

Comment: @GayotFow no, that's not how I read it.  Article 50 says that the treaties will cease to apply after a withdrawal agreement is made OR 2 years after a state indicates it wishes to leave.

I can't see anything that would prohibit a withdrawal agreement being put into place sooner if one were negotiated.

Comment: @NigelHarper only if the withdrawal agreement (which needs to be signed by every member state) specifies an earlier date: *'The Treaties shall cease to apply to the State in question from the date of entry into force of the withdrawal agreement or, failing that, two years after ...'*

Comment: @NigelHarper, the withdrawing member cannot make the withdrawal agreement alone.

Comment: @GayotFow of course they can't, but so what?

Comment: @NigelHarper it would be unrealistic to expect 28 countries to sign an agreement in one day.  That's within the context of the answer's "...the day after the vote..."

Comment: @GayotFow again, of course, and again, so what?  That has nothing to do with article 50 which is what you commented on and I responded to.